# How can i generate a blob url?

Tags: angularjs, blob

I have a function that will determine if the gif is animated or non-animated. Everything is working fine, until i upload those gif to the server, and load it, the blob url is a empty string. How can i generate a blob url for this?

Due to the blob url being empty string, i get parameter 1 is not of type 'blob'

The function below determines if the gif is animated or not.

```
$scope.isNotAnimatedGIF = function(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      var gifInfo = gify.getInfo(reader.result);
      if (gifInfo.images.length <= 1) {
        file.animatedGIF = false;
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        file.animatedGIF = true;
        resolve(false);
      }
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  });
}
```

I am using Angular 1.4.10
Thank you !

Comment: I am not sure, but did u try `reader.readAsDataURL(file);` ? and `function(e){
   $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.path = e.target.result; // blob url
   });
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to create `Blob` url.

> The **URL.createObjectURL()** static method creates a [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) containing a URL representing the object given in the parameter. The URL lifetime is tied to the [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) in the window on which it was created. The new object URL represents the specified [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object or [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) object.

**DEMO**

```js
function createbloburl(file, type) {
  var blob = new Blob([file], {
    type: type || 'application/*'
  });

  file = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  return file;
}
document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
  if (file) {
    file = createbloburl(file, file.type);
    document.querySelector('iframe').src = file;
    //console.log(file)
  }
})
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file">

<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it out !

Comment: I have try out both suggestion and  i found out that, its was not the blob url missing that is causing the issue. The issue was, the after the file is loaded from server it becomes a object type not a file type, i have try changing the object to a file type but the file size is totally different from the original file

Comment: From server side what you getting base64 or something else ?

Comment: I am getting the whole object type from server, instead of a file type. For this issue, i decided to prevent user from saving the animatedGIF, so i will be able to avoid this issue.

Comment: Can you please provide your whole object ? so I can try to convert in blob. And for this * i decided to prevent user from saving the animatedGIF, so i will be able to avoid this issue* you can use accept attribute on img tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this `reader.readAsDataURL(Blob|File)`.

you can find more from [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: Thanks ! will try it out!